# C++'s equivalent of Matlab's randsample

Tags: c++, matlab, equivalence

Is there any cpp's equivalent of the randsample in Matlab. The function randsample in Matlab is as follows:

```
y = randsample(n,k,true,w)
```

which returns a weighted sample taken with replacement, using a vector of positive weights w, whose length is n. The probability that the integer i is selected for an entry of y is w(i)/sum(w).

for example:

```
R = randsample('ACGT', 10,true,[0.15 0.35 0.35 0.15])
```

will have an output

```
CTTCGTCGGG
```

If there is no existing cpp lib having the same function as randsample in Matlab, how to write the equivalent function in cpp?

Comment: No, there is not. If you need it you have to write it by your own (or to rely on an external library).

Answer (score 1):

The Random library of boost helps a lot with this kind of stuff. It's not direct but a least they give you a way to draw samples from a discrete distribution defined by weights.

Comment: Since c++11 there is no need to use boost because you can use the  std::discrete_disitribution class.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution